# Change APIM Azure region

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there a way to modify (instead of adding or removing new ones) the Azure region in APIM?

The UI does not allow that, but I see [this cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/update-azapimanagementregion?view=azps-8.3.0). Not sure it's the correct one.

Comment: What do you mean by modifying? Do you have multi regional apim and wants to update one region?

Comment: No, that's the problem. It's not multi-regional.

Comment: So, do you want to change the primary region of the service to be a different region?

Comment: Correct. That's exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the primary region of a servic. One option would be backip and restore (
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-disaster-recovery-backup-restore?tabs=powershell)

You can create a different service in the other region and use the backup of the primary service to move your service entities.

There are some constrains mentioned in the doc which you need to read carefully.